# Processing, mouse control through Kinect, Telling processing to left click

Tags: java, click, processing, kinect

I was wondering if you guys can help.

I've made a processing sketch that takes my skeleton data and position gives them to my robot class and I can control my mouse pretty nicley.

Only problem is I cant find out how to tell processing to LeftClick, or stay LeftClicked while the if statement is in hold.

```
    kinect.drawLimb(calibratedUserID, 
                          SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_SHOULDER,
                          SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_ELBOW);                            
    //right hand above right elbow
    // and
    // right hand right of right elbow  
     if(leftHand.y > leftElbow.y && leftHand.x > leftElbow.x) {
      stroke(255);
      mousePressed = true; **This being the section i cant figure out!** 
      println("did it work?");
    }else{
      stroke(355, 0, 0);
    }
         kinect.drawLimb(calibratedUserID, 
                          SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_HAND,
                          SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_ELBOW);
  }                        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `r` is an instance of the Robot class:

```
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

[Source 1](http://mrbool.com/simulating-mouse-click-and-keyboard-press-with-java-and-pixel-color-determiner/24487), [Source 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)